# Task.Factory.StartNew with parameters and return values

Tags: c#

Trying to call a method that requires parameters in order to get a result and pass the result to proceed. But I'm new to the Task area and can't seem to figure out the correct syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    CheckConflict(startDate, endDate, actID, repeatRule,whichTime))
    .ContinueWith(
        GetConflictDelegate(result),
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to continue with the result of `CheckConflict()`, [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes a [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as an argument. `Task<T>` has a property `Result`, which will be the result from the method invocation.

See my code snippet below, for an example.

```
new TaskFactory()
.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return 1;
    })
.ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        //Prints out System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Int32]
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        //Prints out 1
        Console.WriteLine(x.Result);
    });
```

Comment: What about TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext? Will the ContinueWith simply know to return the main thread?

Comment: @Rick If the current sync context represents the main thread, yes.  If it doesn't, then it'll return to whatever context it was in.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you use `async`/`await`:

```
var result = await Task.Run(
    () => CheckConflict(startDate, endDate, actID, repeatRule, whichTime);
GetConflictDelegate(result);
```

Comment: What if you are still stuck on .net 4? Whats the options there?

Comment: @Kendo: If you are not on ASP.NET, then you can use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. (which has `TaskEx.Run`).

Comment: I am limited to asp.net 4 unfortunately using mvc. From what i have gathered the async modifier only came into existence in .net 4.5. I have been reading your blog on here http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html (very nice btw) but when trying the await examples its telling me that i need a reference to another assembly and that im targeting the wrong version of .net. I seem to have had some success with TaskFactory but i read that its not very safe. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Kendo: You shouldn't use `Run` or `StartNew` on ASP.NET at all. I suggest you ask a question of your own describing what you're actually trying to do (and note that you're stuck on .NET 4.0).

Comment: Thanks Stephen, ill do just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult>(new Func<TResult>(() =>
{
return 1;
}).ContinueWith<TResult>(new Action((result) =>
{
Console.Writeline(result.Result); // output: 1
});
```

Try this one

Comment: All of the generic arguments to methods and delegates in this code block can simply be inferred, there is no reason to explicitly state them.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `Task<TResult>` class (see [MSDN - TaskFactory.StartNew-Methode (Func, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd321394%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `<TResult>` is the return type of your invoked method.
Because you starting a new thread you have to wait until thread is finished without blocking the main thread or leading the messagepump to stop. This is where you can use async and await.

Assuming a method Calculate() which is taking two parameters of type `double` and returning a result of `double` and a second method called Validate() which validates the result. The solution could look like this:

```
private async Task CalculateAsync()
{
    // Our parameter object
    CustomArgsObject customParameterObject = new CustomArgsObject() 
    {
        Value1 = 500,
        Value2 = 300
    };

    Task<double> returnTaskObject = await Task<double>.Factory.StartNew(
          (paramsHoldingValues)  => Calculate(paramsHoldingValues as CustomArgsObject), 
          customParameterObject);

    // Because of await the following lines will only be executed 
    // after the task is completed while the caller thread still has 'focus'
    double result = returnTaskObject.Result;
    Validate(result);
}

private double Calculate(CustomArgsObject values)
{
    return values.Value1 + values.Value2;
}

private bool Validate(double value)
{
    return (value < 1000);
}
```

The `await` returns focus back to the the caller thread (thread who called CalculateAsync() ) to prevent locking while the task is running. At the same time `await` forces the CalculateAsync() to be processed until the line where the task is started and then waits until the task is completed. The the rest of the CalculateAsync() will then be processed.
Without `await` the whole method would be processed - before the task is finished or simultaneous to the running task.

The `Task<TResult>` class (where `<TResult>` is the placeholder for your return type) has a property `Result` that holds the return value of type `<TResult>`.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
                {
                    return CheckConflict(startDate, endDate, actID, repeatRule,whichTime);

                }).ContinueWith(x=>
                    {
                        GetConflictDelegate(whichTime);
                    },TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: This does not use the result of the first method call in the continuation.

Comment: Correct it uses a value set earlier in the method.