# How to use async and await when one of the methods must be run always

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer, async-await

I have a method that it must be run each five minutes:

```
    public float enConsumption()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            enValue = energyConsumtion(enValue);

            Thread.Sleep(300000);
            Console.WriteLine("Consumation **** ENVALUE" + Convert.ToString(enValue));
            return enValue;

        }
    }
```

In addition, I have an oxyplot graph with 12 elements. I need to pass a float array to it each 2 hours, the value of each element of array is the amount of enConsumption(). Therefore, I wrote this function, the function control the time, if it was in the correct time interval, then it will update the tempList array :

```
 public float[] passEnergyConsumptionToGarph()
    {
        if(compareTime(curruntTime,0,2)){
            tempList[0] = enConsumption();

        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 2, 4))
        {
            tempList[1] = enConsumption();

        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 4, 6))
        {
            tempList[2] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 6, 8))
        {
            tempList[3] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 8, 10))
        {
            tempList[4] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 10, 12))
        {
            tempList[5] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 12, 14))
        {
            tempList[6] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 14, 16))
        {
            tempList[7] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 16, 18))
        {
            tempList[8] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 18, 20))
        {
            tempList[9] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 20, 22))
        {
            tempList[10] = enConsumption();
        }
        if (compareTime(curruntTime, 22, 24))
        {
            tempList[11] = enConsumption();
        }

        return tempList;

        }
```

Finally, I must call the passEnergyConsumptionToGarph() in my main activity in order to pass its result to my oxyplot graph.

Therefore I need to run all the time enConsumption in background and I need to call passEnergyConsumptionToGarph() in the case that user clicks on button show graph. I am new in .net and I need to know how to use async and await in this situation. I would be thankful if you guide me.

UPDATED

Considering to the received responses, I used a timer in order to run the enConsumption() method each 5 min:

```
    public  void timerClass(){

        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
        var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
        {

            enConsumption();


        }, null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);

    }
```

Comment: `async/await` is probably not useful here at all, why do you feel you have to use this? What you should be looking at using is a proper timer, I recommend [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) which is thread safe.

Comment: You can simplify `passEnergyConsumptionToGarph()`: 
    `public float[] passEnergyConsumptionToGarph()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<= 22; i+=2) 
        { 
            if(compareTime(curruntTime, i, i + 2)) 
            {
                tempList[i / 2] = enConsumption();
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the answer. Then I need to return the enConsumption() value. How can I call a method each 5 minute while it also returns the result?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Timer.
You need async/await only when you started new thread or task.
[Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then I need to return the enConsumption() value. How can I call a method each 5 minute while it also returns the result?

Comment: [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291584/task-factory-startnew-with-parameters-and-return-values)

Comment: While `await` *can* be used for managing operations running on another thread, that's not *all* it's good for.  It's there to work with *any* type of asynchronous operation, even though that don't involve other threads.